# ORACLE SQL function that can be used in the where part of a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a function that can be used in the where part of a select statement. Like this:

```
select 'x' from table where addNumber(4,3)=7;
```

I know how to do this in MS SQL, but I would like to do this Oracle SQL. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you should try to determine whether your user defined function (udf) is a deterministic function or not. When your udf is declared as deterministic you can gain performance and you can use your udf in a function based index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a PL/SQL function...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addNumber(firstParam  IN NUMBER,
                                     secondParam IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
BEGIN
   RETURN firstParam + secondParam;
END;
/
```

...run this into the scheam you're using (probably using SQL*Plus) and then call it as you did in your SQL statement above.